Create a render queue
I am trying to create a render queue, using the "complete_render" handler to start a new render job. I am using "bpy.ops.render.render("INVOKE_DEFAULT")". The problems is that I get this error when the second render job starts:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gras/.config/blender/4.2/scripts/addons/360_ez_spinner/operators/render.py", line 99, in render
    bpy.ops.render.render("INVOKE_DEFAULT", write_still=True, animation=True)
  File "/usr/share/blender/4.2/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 107, in __call__
    ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), kw, C_exec, C_undo)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.render.render.poll() Missing 'window' in context

Here is my code, I have tried the sollution in the simillar stack exchange post but the method seems deprecated.
def shut_window():
    # Function to find and "close" the render window
    
    # Get the current screen
    screen = bpy.context.screen

    # Loop through each area in the screen
    # for area in screen.areas:
    #     # Check if the area is an image editor and is showing a render result
    #     if area.type == 'IMAGE_EDITOR' and area.spaces.active.mode == 'VIEW':
    #         # Override the context to close the area
    #         override = bpy.context.copy()
    #         override['area'] = area
    #         bpy.ops.screen.area_close(override)
    #         break  # Exit after closing the first found render editor
  
    # Iterate over all windows
    for window in bpy.context.window_manager.windows:
        # Iterate over all screen areas in the window
        for area in window.screen.areas:
            # Check if the area type is 'IMAGE_EDITOR'
            if area.type == 'IMAGE_EDITOR':
                # Access the area spaces
                # for space in area.spaces:
                #     # Check if the space is set to show the render result
                #     if space.type == 'IMAGE_EDITOR' and space.image and space.image.type == 'RENDER_RESULT':
                #         # Change area type to 'INFO' or any other area type to "close" the render window
                area.type = "VIEW_3D"
                        
                return
        
    return        

def enable_render_button(scene, ren):
    scene.spin_settings.enable_render = True
    bpy.app.handlers.render_complete.remove(enable_render_button)

def render(scene, rend):
    global output_filepath
    global output_queue
    
    print(output_queue)
    
    shut_window()
    # bpy.ops.render.view_cancel('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
            
    hide_render_others(output_queue[0])
    set_current_camera_as_render(output_queue[0])
    
    if len(output_queue) == 1:
        if render in bpy.app.handlers.render_complete:
            bpy.app.handlers.render_complete.remove(render)
        bpy.app.handlers.render_complete.append(enable_render_button)
    
    output_path = output_filepath + "/" + output_queue[0] + "/" + output_queue[0] + "_"

    
    bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.file_format = 'PNG'  # Output file format
    bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = output_path
    
    # remove after render, order matters
    output_queue.pop(0)
    
    # Perform the render
    bpy.ops.render.render("INVOKE_DEFAULT", write_still=True, animation=True)

    


class OBJECTE_OT_render(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.render"
    bl_label = "Render the list"
    bl_description = "Render the list of output objects with the appropriate settings"    


    def execute(self, context):
        global output_list
        global output_queue
        
        output_queue = output_list.copy()
        
        
        bpy.app.handlers.render_complete.append(render)
        # bpy.context.scene.spin_settings.enable_render = False
        render(None, None)
            
        return {"FINISHED"}

